# File has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime error SceneBuilder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I've used JLink + JPackage to build a JavaFX app into a self-contained application. I'm using JDK 14. However, when I try to open one of my FXML files in IntelliJ's Scenebuilder I get this error:

`File has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0.`

To run the app in development environment, I use `mvn clean javafx:run`.

When I check in the IDE's compiler settings, the JDK is correctly set to 14, and so is the `JAVA_HOME` variable, as shown below. How do I fix this?

```
PS C:\dev> java --version
openjdk 14.0.2 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Can you clarify? The app runs, but you get this error when opening an FXML file in SceneBuilder? Can you open SceneBuilder on its own (i.e. just run it, without opening a file)? This just sounds like you are trying to run SceneBuilder with the wrong JDK.

Comment: Yes, the app runs without trouble, I only get the error when trying to edit it with SceneBuilder. SceneBuilder also works fine on it's own, and I can even edit newly created FXML files - I just can't edit the ones that were already compiled.

Comment: Actually I just realized that I can edit most files, the only ones that throw this error are the files that use custom fxml components that I created.

Comment: On my Mac (not sure how to do the equivalent on Windows), I can right-click on the SceneBuilder app and choose "Show package contents", which shows the structure of the application. If I dig down in there (`/Contents/Plugins/Java.runtime/Contents/Home/bin`, though this is platform-dependent) I can find the `java` executable, and from there verify SceneBuilder is running with Java 11. If you have custom components, I assume SceneBuilder loads the relevant classes, which will cause the error you see for obvious reasons.

Comment: So... I guess, try building SceneBuilder yourself (https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder) so you can run it under JDK14? That seems like a bit of a sledgehammer solution...

Comment: Since you're familiar with `jpackage`, if you can extract the jar file from the SceneBuilder exe, you could repackage it with JDK14 and JavaFX 14 and create a new SceneBuilder exe. Then configure IntelliJ to point to the repackaged SceneBuilder. Still seems like there should be an easier solution, though...

Comment: Version 55 means that scene builder supports just up to Java 11.  58 is Java 14. You either have to compile it to 11 or see if you can get a newer version of scenebuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the problem are your custom components. You have probably compiled them with Java 14 and put the resulting jars into SceneBuilder. So each time when you load an FXML file which uses one of these components you will get that error message because the class file version of your components is younger than the version of SceneBuilder itself. For compatibility reasons it would be a good idea to compile your components with a target 11 anyway. You can do that with your Java 14 compiler. This would increase compatibility in general and solve your problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I think (I'm not 100% sure but it makes sense) there are 2 answer's to this...

1. Your intellij is using an older version of java (It can range from 6 to 13). So you would need to allow intellij to use a newer version of java (JDK14).
2. Build your application with older version of java, of course you might need to change some functions because of older version of java.

Comment: I think 1. is not quite correct. IntelliJ launches SceneBuilder, which is a separate Java application which bundles a JVM (to appear as a native application). It's the Java version bundled in SceneBuilder (not IntelliJ) which is the issue. (AFAICT this would necessitate repackaging SceneBuilder, using `jpackage` or similar.)